# Route [admin.categories.index] not defined

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to get a categories page but it says:

> Route [admin.categories.index] not defined.

**Controller:**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {
        return view('admin.categories.index');
    }

}
```

**Routes:**

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin\Auth')->name('admin.')
->group(function () {
//Login Routes
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

//Admin Categories Route
Route::resource('category','CategoryController');
});

Route::get('/admin/home', 'Admin\HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
```

Comment: Do `php artisan route:list` and see if a route with that name is defined.

Comment: it says: https://ibb.co/kHHhhXg

Comment: OK, so fix that error, and any others, until you get a route list. Then look at the list, which will include each route's name.

Comment: still unable to resolve it

Comment: Remove *everything* that you can in your routes file, and just leave the category routes.  Start from there, see if that will work.  If so, build the rest back in until you have a route list.

Comment: if i put this route: Route::resource('category','CategoryController'); outside the admin  route group function then it works fine but in admin route group  function it show error

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```php
Route::resource('category','CategoryController');
```

to this:

```php
Route::resource('categories','CategoryController');
```

Comment: now it says:  Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\CategoryController does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is calling the route (a blade page linking to the route?) is calling for:

```
route(admin.categories.index)
```

or perhaps

```
yoursite/admin/categories/index
```

or your might be using `$router->` ... etc.  Whatever is calling the route is looking for a route that doesn't exist (thus the error).  You have defined the route as:

```
Route::resource('category','CategoryController');
```

There is no `admin` in that resource.  Either change the resource, or much easier, **just remove** '`admin`' **from whatever is calling the route**.

Remember, the code you have shown in the `index()` method above, `return view('admin.categories.index');`, doesn't have anything to do with the route - it is just pointing to a folder within the views directory called admin, subfolder called categories, file called index.